# MongoDB to Snowflake continuous loading

Tags: mongodb, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have source data that are structured as events in MongoDB and we are building a data warehouse in Snowflake. Each type of event relates to an operation in the DW, such as a row insert or a update etc.

How can I continuously load data from MongoDB into Snowflake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have (at least) two options:

1. Use an integration tool such as dbt:
   https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ecosystem-etl.html
2. Create your own bespoke pipleline with SnowPipe via a storage integration. This will involve creating a process that exports the events from MongoDB to cloud storage. Obviously, this process needs to keep track of which events have already been processed.
   https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-intro.html
   https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-storage-integration.html